CSS just ignore hover scale effect if I animate the container
Growing animation transform: scale(1.1) doesn't working if I set animation: fadeInX 0.5s ease forwards; to div. I don't have any idea how to solve this. I tried moving the hover effect to a separate animation but it doesn't work.
@keyframes fadeInX {
  to {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}

div{
    transform:translateX(-300px) scale(1);
    animation: fadeInX 0.5s ease forwards;
}

div:hover{
        cursor:pointer;
        transform: scale(1.1);
}


You need to either set the wrapper and apply scale to it, or changeanimation-fill-mode and animation itself:


@keyframes fadeInX {
  from{
    transform:translateX(-100%)
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}

div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  animation: fadeInX 0.5s ease;
  transition: transform .5s;
}

div:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
<div></div>




Solved my problem, CSS is complex as hell, thank you
